# Overloading operator for a priority queue

Tags: c++, data-structures, compiler-errors, operator-overloading, priority-queue

I am trying to overload the () operator for a priority queue to use with my Cell objects.

Each Cell object has the function:

`static int GetCost(const Cell first, const Cell second);`

Which returns the cost from `first` Cell to `second`.

Now I have a priority queue like this:

`priority_queue<Cell*, std::vector<Cell*>, Comparator> path;`

My priority queue must be a pointer queue.

I want to add Cells in the priority queue based on the cost of the Cell (which is returned from `GetCost()`) so after founding some examples around the web I tried doing this:

```
struct Comparator
    {
        bool operator()(const Cell lfs, const Cell rhs)
        {
            return Cell::GetCost(lfs, rhs) < Cell::GetCost(rhs, lfs);
        }
    };
```

But this gives me the error:

`Error  4   error C2664: 'bool AI::Comparator::operator ()(const Cell,const Cell)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'Cell *' to 'const Cell'`

I have already tried changing it to this:

```
bool operator()(Cell* const lfs, Cell* const rhs)
        {
            return Cell::GetCost(*lfs, *rhs) < Cell::GetCost(*rhs, *lfs);
        }
```

but this gives me an even worse error:

`Error  4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static int __cdecl Cell::GetCost(class Cell,class Cell)" (?GetCost@Cell@@SAHV1@0@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall AI::Comparator::operator()(class Cell * const,class Cell * const)" (??RComparator@AI@@QAE_NQAVCell@@0@Z)`

I have already tried changing

`static int GetCost(const Cell first, const Cell second)`

to

`static int GetCost(const Cell* first, const Cell* second)`

error I got was:

`Error  4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static int __cdecl Cell::GetCost(class Cell const *,class Cell const *)" (?GetCost@Cell@@SAHPBV1@0@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall AI::Comparator::operator()(class Cell * const,class Cell * const)" (??RComparator@AI@@QAE_NQAVCell@@0@Z)`

Here is the whole GetCost:

```
static int GetCost(const Cell first, const Cell second)
{
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < first.neighbors.size(); k++)
    {
        if (first.neighbors[k].cell->row == second.row &&
            first.neighbors[k].cell->column == second.column)
        {
            return first.neighbors[k].weight;
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried changing it to pointers but it did not work.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly whats wrong and gives you a (IMO) very clear hint about what to do. Always read the error (and warning!) messages.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Obviously, I have already tried numerous other stuff like the one I just edited but I wanted to post the most simple error to get some help.

Comment: Where and how did you define your `GetCost` function?

Comment: You *do* have the `GetCost` static method implemented somewhere? By the way, you may want to change it to use pointers as well, or take its arguments by reference.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley GetCost is defined in another file. How it is defined I have already written it above.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I do have implemented it, even Visual Studio knows that it's there and I also have already tried changing it to pointers

Comment: @Powerbyte: No, you have not shown how `GetCost` is defined.  You've only shown how it is declared.

Comment: This doesn't fix it (that's what answers are for), but you should really pass by reference, not value, i.e. `const Cell &lfs` as opposed to `const Cell lfs` (otherwise you're unnecessarily copying the object).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I posted the whole GetCost function

Comment: @Powerbyte: See the addition to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your priority queue stores `Cell` pointers (`Cell*`), but your function compares `Cell` objects (`Cell`).  One of these things needs to change to match the other.

In regards to your linker error, in your implementation file, change this:

```
static int GetCost(const Cell first, const Cell second)
{
    ...
}
```

to this:

```
int Cell::GetCost(const Cell first, const Cell second)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: That was the root of my problems in the end....That Cell::GetCost...I just can't believe that was what was causing most of my errors. The queue seems to be working now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a type-mismatch problem. Please check the code where you invoke the Comparator struct in you priority_queue class, verify the parameters you use. The operator () needs Cell instance or Cell reference. Maybe you pass the pointers of Cell to () operator.